# Dúvida na implementação da função ode45 do Matlab

Tags: matlab

Nunca utilizei a função ode45 do Matlab. Abaixo a função e o programa que desenvolvi, alguém, por gentileza, pode me ajudar a encontrar os erros?

-Função

function di=didt(t,i,flag,R,L,v,f,Rsec) 
i1=i(1);
i2=i(2);
A=L;
D=L*R;
w=2*pi*f;

di(1)=A(1,1)*(v*cos(w*t))+A(1,2)*Rsec*i2+A(1,3)*((D(3,1)*i1+D(3,2)*i2...
    -A(3,1)*(v*cos(w*t))-A(3,2)*Rsec*i2)/A(3,3))-D(1,1)*i1-D(1,2)*i2;
di(2)=A(2,1)*(v*cos(w*t))+A(2,2)*Rsec*i2+A(2,3)*((D(3,1)*i1+D(3,2)*i2...
    -A(3,1)*(v*cos(w*t))-A(3,2)*Rsec*i2)/A(3,3))-D(2,1)*i1-D(2,2)*i2;
di=[di(1) di(2)]';

end

-Programa

% Definição dos parâmetros
R=[2.1581 0 0; 0 0.0114 0; 0 0 0.0556];
L=[8.7492 -8.7828 0.0336; -8.7828 12.3082 -3.5254; 0.0336 -3.5254 3.4918];
f=1e3;
v=10e3;
Rsec=100;
i10=0;
i20=0;

% Tempo de simulação
t=[0 10e-3];

[t,i]=ode45('didt',t,[i10 i20],[],R,L,v,f,Rsec)
figure(1)
plot(t,i(:,1), t,i(:,2))

Comment: Por favor especifique o que você quer fazer com seu programa.

Comment: @FábioPerez preciso encontrar as correntes i1 e i2 usando a função ode45 do Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Há diversos problemas de digitação da sua definição da função e para ter certeza da resposta seria necessário que mostrasse o modelo original que está tentando simular. Tentando fazer uma correção prévia sem essa informação, um programa que funciona é o seguinte:

Definição do sistema:

```
function di=didt(t,i,R,L,v,f,Rsec) 

i1=i(1); i2=i(2); A=L; D=L*R; w=2*pi*f;

di(1,1)=A(1,1)*(v*cos(w*t))+A(1,2)*Rsec*i2+A(1,3)*((D(3,1)*i1+D(3,2)*i2... 
    -A(3,1)*(v*cos(w*t))-A(3,2)*Rsec*i2)/A(3,3))-D(1,1)*i1-D(1,2)*i2; 
di(2,1)=A(2,1)*(v*cos(w*t))+A(2,2)*Rsec*i2+A(2,3)*((D(3,1)*i1+D(3,2)*i2...
    -A(3,1)*(v*cos(w*t))-A(3,2)*Rsec*i2)/A(3,3))-D(2,1)*i1-D(2,2)*i2;

end
```

Programa para a simulação:

```
% Definição dos parâmetros 
R=[2.1581 0 0; 0 0.0114 0; 0 0 0.0556]; 
L=[8.7492 -8.7828 0.0336; -8.7828 12.3082 -3.5254; 0.0336 -3.5254 3.4918];
f=1e3; v=10e3; Rsec=100; i10=0; i20=0;

% Tempo de simulação
ts=[0 10e-3];

[t,i]=ode45(@(t,y) didt(t,y,R,L,v,f,Rsec),ts ,[i10 i20])
figure(1) 
plot(t,i(:,1), t,i(:,2))
```

Note que havia o parâmetro `flag` não utilizado e que para chamar a função `ode45` com parâmetros auxiliares para a função é necessário definir uma função anônima como foi feito ali `@(t,y) didt(t,y,R,L,v,f,Rsec)`.